# How to create an outlook pst file for each user outlook

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

Is it possible via GPO to create and assign a new PST file to every user'a outlook  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of...  You can tell MS Outlook to generate a PST in a particular place.  You need the Office .ADM / .ADMX files.

PSTs ... really? ;-)